# Fragment transition using androidx.transition.Slide seems to reorder view z index

Tags: android, kotlin, android-transitions

When using `Slide` transition to enter/exit a `Frament`, it seems views are reordered when exiting animation is played. There no much code to talk about just this simple line to activate the transition from a `Fragment`, all views are inside a `ConstraintLayout` so not much there neither:

```
 override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        enterTransition = Slide().setDuration(1000)
}
```

Is there anything to manage this zindex reordering?

Here are some captures and a projet example :

[image]
[image]

From first capture everything fine all inputs are in front of image.
From second capture you ca see second input is behind image, this is totally random sometime more inputs are behind image.
You can grab an example project from this [repository](https://github.com/SamYStudiO/transitions), click "GO PROFILE" button and then click back. Transition is implemented in this file `net.samystudio.beaver.ui.main.authenticator.AuthenticatorFragment`

Thx for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found out that ordering transition from a `TransitionSet` influence depth so workaround is to set `Slide` transition for image before other elements like this :

```
TransitionSet()
   .addTransition(
      Slide()
         .addTarget(R.id.image)
   )
   .addTransition(
      Slide()
         .excludeTarget(R.id.image, true)
   )
   .setDuration(5000)
```

I'm not sure this is intended so.